# How to populate up variables from included twig template

Tags: php, templates, twig

I want to be able to populate up variables from included twig templates, just like when you're extending another template. Here's an example:

I have base.twig as follows:

```
{# base.twig #}
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body class="body {{class_from_index}}">
        <nav>...</nav>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        <footer>...</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

and index.twig as follows:

```
{# index.twig #}
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% set class_from_index = 'index' }

{% block content %}
    <div>My actual content</div>
{% endblock %}
```

doing like this, the variable `class_from_index` is populated to `base.twig`, when I'm rendering `index.twig`. 
However if i have gallery.twig like this:

```
{# gallery.twig #}
{% set class_from_index = 'gallery' %}
<div>
    A gallery
</div>
```

and adding `{% include gallery.twig %}` in `index.twig`, the variable `class_from_index` is not populated up to `index.twig` or `base.twig`. I know that if `gallery.twig` extends `index.twig` and `index.twig` extends `base.twig`, this will work, but this is not the case.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to explain? 
Thank you :)

Comment: How are you rendering "gallery.twig"? I would either extend it from "index.twig" or use a Twig "use" statement to conditionally include "gallery.twig" with blocks. And I'd use a block instead of a variable.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention it. I use it like `{% include gallery.twig %}` . Including templates with `use template.twig` still doesn't populated the variables up.

Comment: Blocks are more suitable for what you are doing. And I think you'll have to use `{% use gallery.twig %}` instead of `{% include %}`. Although I think you'll have more luck inheriting `gallery.twig` from `index.twig`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

If <kbd>main.twig</kbd> contains:

```
{% include "gallery.twig" %}
```

The compiled result will be:

```
protected function doDisplay(array $context, array $blocks = array())
{
    // line 1
    $this->loadTemplate("gallery.twig", "main.twig", 1)->display($context);
}
```

And if <kbd>gallery.twig</kbd> contains:

```
{% set var = 42 %}
```

The result is:

```
protected function doDisplay(array $context, array $blocks = array())
{
    // line 1
    $context["var"] = 42;
}
```

As you can see, the context is not given as a reference, so your variable can't be populated.

## The PHP equivalent

The reason is quite obvious. It looks very exotic to use variables from a lower scope to a upper one. That's like if you were doing in PHP:

```
<?php

function gallery() {
  $var = 42;
}
gallery();

echo $var;
```

There must be a better solution to your problem... by designing your templates architecture another way. The question itself is not relevant, that's totally out of good practices.

Comment: Thank for your answer. The thing I wanted to is to add "modules" into a variable. So when I load index.twig, the default css +js would be included, but when I include gallery.twig, it will add specific css + js for the gallery to work. In gallery.twig I would have something like `{% set css = css|merge(['gallery.css']) %}` and then i would include that gallery.css inside the head in `base.twig`. Something like dynamic module including, when the modules are css & js code. I'll research into extending the twig compiler, so that I can populate up variables.

Comment: You're welcome. You really need to look closer at blocks, that's the way to go.